# How to format fastify logs as logfmt

Tags: node.js, logging, fastify

We have very strict rule: all microservices should write their logs using [logfmt](https://brandur.org/logfmt) format. By default, [fastify](https://fastify.dev/) using json formatting. This is the only thing that stops us from using this framework.

I want fastify to write logs using logfmt formatting. Are there any ways to achieve this?

Comment: (Disclaimer I'm the maintainer) I've written a logfmt transport for pino (fastify's logger). The transport is based on the https://npmjs.com/package/logfmt package. Here is my package https://npmjs.com/package/pino-logfmt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fastify uses pino logger under the hood so you need a pino transport to have it:
https://github.com/pinojs/pino/blob/master/docs/transports.md

If it misses, you may implement and then fastify will work consequently